# How to get the FPS from Android Camera Preview?

Tags: android, camera, frame-rate, preview

Have any way to get the FPS(frame per second) from the android camera preview?
Could i get the preview FPS by android log or special FPS estimate APK?
Have any general purpose to get FPS information on every APPs which include the function of camera preview?

Have any ideal or suggestion?

Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `setPreviewTexture()` API, you can monitor the framerate with `SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener` . If you are using  `setPreviewDisplay()` , you can add a preview callbacks through the `setPreviewCallback()` method. In both cases the callbacks will trigger every time a new frame is available.